# Can't modify samba share files on container from MAC host

Tags: linux, macos, docker, containers, samba

I'm running docker container. Having arch linux running there.

Inside the container I have some folders/files which I want to access from my MAC.

I'm using samba share to share the files from the container to my MAC. So far it's working so that I can see the files, browse them and open them. 
The problem is that I can't modify them, every time I try to do that I get permission denied. Seeing the permissions it's says I have the **rwx** on the folder I've shared but the files inside that folder only have **r--** permissions. (viewing this from inside the container)

Before I created the share I also created a new user called User1 and used that when mounting using **mount_smbfs**.

My smb.conf has the following set up:

```
[myshare]
   comment = development
   path = /tmp
   valid users = User1
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0775
   directory mask = 0775
   force user = User1
```

Comment: what is your selinux status? is it enforcing?

Comment: Don't have such thing as selinux.

Comment: can you check the umask? you might need to use `force create mode` to set the permission.

Comment: Says that the umask is 0022.

Comment: you either need to change the umask or set the `force create mode` to 0775

Answer (score 0):

You should check the manual of [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html). Possibly that the umask is strict that the newly created files do not have enough permission for user to write or execute.

> create mask (S)
>
> When a file is created, the necessary permissions are calculated according to the mapping from DOS modes to UNIX
>   permissions, and the resulting UNIX mode is then
>              bit-wise 'AND'ed with this parameter. This parameter may be thought of as a bit-wise MASK for the UNIX modes of a file. Any bit
>   not set here will be removed from
>              the modes set on a file when it is created.
>
> force create mode (S)
>
> This parameter specifies a set of UNIX mode bit permissions that will always be set on a file created by Samba. This is done by
>   bitwise 'OR'ing these bits onto the
>              mode bits of a file that is being created. The default for this parameter is (in octal) 000. The modes in this parameter are
>   bitwise 'OR'ed onto the file mode
>              after the mask set in the create mask parameter is applied.